# More elegant way to generate adjacency matrix from list of tuples

Tags: python, function, graph, adjacency-matrix

Suppose we start with a "friendship" graph represented by a list of tuples,

```
friendships = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2,
3), (3, 4),(4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

where element 0 is a friend of 1 (and hence 1 is a friend of 0).

I want to construct the adjacency matrix **from scratch** in a way that will always work for this type of tuple representation.

I have the following (repulsive) Python code:

```py
def make_matrix(num_rows,num_cols,entry_fn):
    return [[entry_fn(i,j)
             for j in range(num_cols)]
            for i in range(num_rows)]
def adjacency(connections):
    new=connections+[(x[1],x[0]) for x in connections]
    elements=list(set([x[0] for x in connections]+ [x[1] for x in connections]))
    def test(i,j):
        if (elements[i],elements[j]) in new:
            return 1
        else: return 0
    return make_matrix(len(elements),len(elements),test)
```

I know that it is inefficient and very ugly. Is there a smarter way to solve this problem? The output for the example list that I gave above should be

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

**update:**
as per one of the answers, I have the following possible solution, although I don't know if it's any better

```py
def adj(connections):
    ##step 1
    temp=(set(elem[0] for elem in connections).union(
        set(elem[1] for elem in connections)))
    n=max(temp)+1
    ans=[]
    ##step 2
    for i,_ in enumerate(temp):
        ans.append([])
        for j,_ in enumerate(temp):
            ans[i].append(0)
    ##step 3
    for pair in connections:
        ans[pair[0]][pair[1]]=1
        ans[pair[1]][pair[0]]=1
    return ans
```

Comment: Do you know the number of vertices ahead of time?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no, which is part of the challenge and the reason I have this gross elements definition in the middle

Comment: from scratch- does this mean you're actually looking for native solutions only and libraries are out of the picture?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes. I'm not interested in a graph/network library that has an adjacency function that you can call.

Answer (score 6):

My algorithm would be something like this:

1. Find the maximum vertex id. Call this `n`.
2. Create an `n+1` by `n+1` array of zeros. Call this `M`.
3. For each pair `x, y` in the input list, set `M[x][y] = 1`

To come up with this solution, I first thought of step 3. With the given input, this seems the most straightforward way to populate the adjacency matrix. However, it requires a 2D array of a fixed size. So the problem is how do I figure out `n` for step 2. From there it doesn't take much thought to figure out step 1 is what is needed.

The details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `n` should be one more than the maximum ID

Comment: @TavianBarnes Alternatively, the array's dimensions should be one more than `n`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice first of all, I appreciate your answer. Is this algorithm very different from what is currently written in the original post? I would actually appreciate an implementation because I get the sense that the way I've written the function is very ugly (and probably slow.)

Comment: @AndresMejia " Is this algorithm very different from what is currently written in the original post?" Which line of code in your OP finds the maximum vertex id? I don't see that step anywhere, so I conclude that my algorithm is very different from yours.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice okay I will think about it. Maybe it is unclear to me what you mean by maximum vertex id? I guess for me len(elements) accomplishes the goal of finding the appropriate dimension of my matrix.

Comment: I'll take what you say literally, and try to translate it to python.

Comment: @AndresMejia By "vertex id", I am referring to the elements in each pair. For example `(0, 1)` is refers to two different vertex ids: `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice please check the update, I still have this nagging suspicion that it is not as nice as could be. Is this more or less along the lines of your answer?

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, that code looks like it translates my pseudocode here very closely. There is one flaw in the logic however. For example if `connections` is `[(1, 2), (5, 3)]`, then `n` should be 6. I leave it as an exercise for you to find the problem. You may find [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helpful.

Comment: @AndresMejia "I still have this nagging suspicion that it is not as nice as could be" This feeling will haunt you no matter how long you code. We just improve as we gain experience and sometimes "good enough" is good enough.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, maybe you are right. I'll continue onward :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not much of a Python programmer, but something like...

```
def to_adjacency_matrix(pairs):
  size = 1 + max(map(max, pairs))
  a = [[0 for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)]
  for i, j in pairs:
    a[i][j] = a[j][i] = 1
  return a
```

Comment: Also, your calculation for `size` is not quite correct. For example if `pairs = [(1, 10), (5, 2)]` then size will be assigned `6` instead of the correct value of `11`. Note that `reduce(max, foo)` is equivalent to `max(foo)`.

Comment: Tip: for initializing `a`, you can simplify the inner list comprehension using the `*` operator. `a = [[0] * size] for i in range(size)]`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry typed `reduce` while thinking `map`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Also I actually wrote `[[0] * size]` initially and then changed it. You can't say `[[0] * size] * size` because this is an array of references to the same array. So the way above seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want short and easy-readable solution (and you are planning to work with graph later) I recommend you to use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) library. Your problem can be solved with pair of lines:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(friendships)
nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
```

which will return numpy matrix:

```
matrix([[0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

or

`nx.adjacency_matrix(G)`

which will return scipy sparse matrix:

```
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
import numpy as np

def adjacency(connections):
    n_people = max(sum(connections, ())) + 1
    mat = np.zeros((n_people, n_people), dtype='int')
    for friend1, friend2 in connections:
        mat[friend1, friend2] = 1
        mat[friend2, friend1] = 1
    return mat
```

and if by "from scratch" you mean that you don't want to use numpy:

```
def adjacency(connections):
    n_people = max(sum(connections, ())) + 1
    mat = [[0 for _ in range(n_people)] for _ in range(n_people)]
    for friend1, friend2 in connections:
        mat[friend1][friend2] = 1
        mat[friend2][friend1] = 1
    return mat
```